# Pandas conditional lookup based on columns from a different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have searched but found no answers for my problem. My first dataframe looks like:

```
df1

Item    Value
1   23
2   3
3   45
4   65
5   17
6   6
7   18
…   … 
500 78
501 98
```

and the second lookup table looks like

```
df2

L1  H1  L2  H2  L3  H3  L4  H4  L5  H5  Name
1   3   5   6   11  78  86  88  90  90  A
4   4   7   10  79  85  91  99  110 120 B
89  89  91  109 0   0   0   0   0   0   C
...
```

What I am trying to do is to get Name from df2 to df1 when Item in df1 falls between the Low (L) and High (H) columns. Something (which does not work) like:

```
df1[Name]=np.where((df1['Item']>=df2['L1'] & df1['Item']<=df2['H1'])|
(df1['Item']>=df2['L2'] & df1['Item']<=df2['H2']) |
(df1['Item']>=df2['L3'] & df1['Item']<=df2['H3']) |
(df1['Item']>=df2['L4'] & df1['Item']<=df2['H4']) |
(df1['Item']>=df2['L5'] & df1['Item']<=df2['H5']) |
(df1['Item']>=df2['L6'] & df1['Item']<=df2['H6']), df2['Name'], "Other")
```

So that the result would be like:

```
Item    Value   Name
1   23  A
2   3   A
3   45  A
4   65  B
5   17  A
6   6   A
7   18  A
…   …   …
500 78  K
501 98  Other
```

If you have any guidance for my problem to share, I would much appreciate it! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

1. Transform `df2` using [`wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html)
2. Create lists of numbers from "L" to "H" for each row using `apply` and `range`
3. `explode` to have one value in each row
4. `map` each "Item" in `df1` using a `dict` created from `ranges` with the structure `{value: name}`

```
ranges = pd.wide_to_long(df2, ["L","H"], i="Name", j="Subset")
ranges["values"] = ranges.apply(lambda x: list(range(x["L"], x["H"]+1)), axis=1)
ranges = ranges.explode("values").reset_index()

df1["Name"] = df1["Item"].map(dict(zip(ranges["values"], ranges["Name"])))

>>> df1
   Item  Value Name
0     1     23    A
1     2      3    A
2     3     45    A
3     4     65    B
4     5     17    A
5     6      6    A
6     7     18    B
7   500     78  NaN
8   501     98  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

A faster option (tests can prove/debunk that), would be to use [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) ([conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) uses binary search underneath the hood):

```py
#pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
temp = (pd.wide_to_long(df2, 
                        stubnames=['L', 'H'], 
                        i='Name', 
                        j='Num')
          .reset_index('Name')
        )

# the `Num` index is sorted already
(df1.conditional_join(
            temp, 
            # left column, right column, join operator
            ('Item', 'L', '>='), 
            ('Item', 'H', '<='),
            how = 'left')
    .loc[:, ['Item', 'Value', 'Name']]
)
   Item  Value Name
0     1     23    A
1     2      3    A
2     3     45    A
3     4     65    B
4     5     17    A
5     6      6    A
6     7     18    B
7   500     78  NaN
8   501     98  NaN
```